# Adding events dynamically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here's a scernerio that will get what I am trying to accomplish....

Say I have a form with a textbox to enter a number and a button called "Create"
When a user enters a number and clicks create the form gets populated with the number of buttons entered in the textbox and the title of the buttons are labeled by consecutive numbers.

For example if you enter 5 the form will populate with 5 buttons labeled button1, button2, ...button5

When you click on these newly created buttons a messagebox will popup stating the buttons name.

Basically I need to know how to create events and populate them with code I guess

dynamically.

Please respond in a solution for a windows app not web. No JavaScript.

Please can someone respond with a code example this idea is a little foggy to me

Comment: This is windows not web sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        'Make sure that the textbox contains a number.
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then

        'Make sure that it's a positive number.
        If CInt(TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then

            For i = 1 To CInt(TextBox1.Text)

                Dim x As New Button
                x.Name = "Button" & i.ToString
                x.Top = 100 + (i * 30) 'To avoid stacking.
                AddHandler x.Click, AddressOf y 'Add the event here.

                'Add it to the form.
                Controls.Add(x)

            Next

        End If

    End If

    Private Sub y(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    MsgBox(CType(sender, Button).Name)

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "add event here"?Say it's a click event can you add that code....and thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh that's the body....can you put some code in the body of the event so I can see it? Sorry it's kinda foggy to me

Comment: Sry the code block can't totally be viewed in my phone....I see how you did it now. Thanks again much appeciated